# Standard inheritance with Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have my base class (let's call it BaseEntityModel) which is abstract and has an Id property:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have another class:

```
public class CarEntityModel : BaseEntityModel
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get only one table: CarEntityModel. The table should have a column for the id and the year. So this is not Table Per Hierarchy nor Table Per Type. Is this possible? How is it called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table-per-concrete and Table-per-hierarchy, in this case would both produce a single table with both Id and Year.  However, with Table per Concrete type, as soon as you introduce another type inheriting from BaseEntityModel, you will have a second table.

"have a column for the id and the year. So this is not Table Per Hierarchy"

This is exactly what Table Per hierarchy does.  If you have two different types, inheriting from a common base class, all the columns from all types are represented in a single table.

Table per Hierarchy:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Table per Concrete:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

I would caution you to avoid inheritance with Entity Framework however.  I was once tempted to do so for the sake of producing a very pleasing object oriented design, but the queries it produces perform terribly.  Table Per hierarchy is a horrible structure IMO because between two types some columns are not used, making the table structure misleading.  The other inheritance approaches produce UNION queries for what I found to be the most common use cases(querying across the base type).  I was very much in love with EF's support for inheritance, and after some time I finally let that bitter sweet love go.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I have the feeling that when using EF you're forced to violate OOP :(.

Comment: @mosquito87 Unfrotunately, but consider within OOP it is encouraged to favor composition over inheritance.  If I have a Vehicaly, Car:Vehicle, and Truck:Vehicle, usually I have one table for Vehicle, and then a 1 to 1/0 relationship to each of Car and Truck, with a VehicleType on the Vehicle table.  It is not perfect because you still have to conditionally join based on type, but usually you're either querying across all Vehicles, or only a particular type of vehicles.  You'd almost never had a query that retrieves both some Car specific columns and Truck specific columns at the same time.